# uploading a file using kendo ui passing the parameter with URL

Tags: kendo-ui

In kendo ui upload ,how can i pass the parameter with save URL while uploading file sync?  if i can use save-field parameter can u tell me how to use it?

```
 $("#files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
    saveUrl: URL + "SaveUrl",
    autoupload: false,
    saveField: "**what to give here?????**",
    },
```

This is my code check can i what to give in the save field if the save field is act like a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

According to kendo documentation:

> The name of the form field which is submitted to *saveUrl*. The default value is the input name.

So this mean it only changes the field submitted.

However here is one possible solution:
[Pass Javascript/html Variable as Parameter with Kendo MVC upload control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794807/pass-javascript-html-variable-as-parameter-with-kendo-mvc-upload-control)

And the JS version:

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
    multiple: false,
    async: {
        saveUrl: URL_HERE,
        autoUpload: true
    },
    upload: function(e){
        console.log(e)
        e.data = { id: JSVariable};
    }
});
```