# Pass Javascript/html Variable as Parameter with Kendo MVC upload control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Have a requirement to pass additional parameter with value of parameter set from javaScript or HTML field.

Example in below case how I can pass HTML element value or Javascript variable value to **uploadID**.

Note: Have limitation to use ViewModel in this place.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("files")
    .Async(a => a
        .Save("Save", "Upload", new { uploadID = "XXX" })
        .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
        .AutoUpload(true)
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Need to get JavaScript variable value in place of "XXX", as this controller is within server tag @(), cannot directly assign value. is there a way to get value of HTML hidden field for XXX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("files")
    .Async(a => a
        .Save("Save", "Upload")
        .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
        .AutoUpload(true)
    )
    .Events(e => e
        .Upload(@<text>
            function(e) {    
                e.data = { uploadID: your_js_variable };
            }
        </text>)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Able pass value and get at controller with this.

Comment: Need another Help. The JS variable assigned for e.data{}, is set to initial value set on page load and not reflecting the updated value set in html later. Is there any way to refresh Kendo Upload Controller to consider latest value

Comment: That's very interesting - I would have thought that Kendo was grabbing the value each time an upload is initiated. Perhaps try passing in a function instead (I've never tried this before so not sure if it's possible)? `e.data = { uploadID: func_that_calculates_value() };` You may need to create a new question as it's a bit difficult to lay everything out in just the comments area.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
@Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("files").Async(a => a
.Save("Async_Save", "ActionCtl")
.Events(events => events.Upload("onUpload")))

<script>
function onUpload(e) {
                    e.data = { ItemBankId: @Model.ItemID };
                }
</script>
```